# Circle method on things other than the integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, additive-combinatorics

The circle method is often used to estimate the number of solutions to the equation $$x_1 + x_2 + ... x_k = N$$ if for all $i$ $x_i\in A\subseteq\mathbb{N}_0$ and some subset of the nonnegative integers. When we try to use the circle method if $A$ isn't a subset of the nonnegative integers, one runs into issues, since the generating function isn't a polynomial or a fourier series. How would one use the circle method or variants of it to estimate the number of solutions of $$x_1 + x_2 + ... x_k = N$$ if for all $i$, $x_i\in A$, if $A$ is some subset of the real numbers or complex numbers.

Comment: What other subsets do you have in mind?

Comment: The Gaussian integers, and subsets of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circle method is a very powerful and versatile tool which can be made to work in a wide range of situations. It certainly works over number fields, see for example

Skinner - Forms over number fields and weak approximation.

The circle method can even be made to work over function fields, see e.g.

Lee - Forms in many variables over algebraic function fields.